# How to truthfully answer auto insurance questions when you don't know the answer?

Tags: car-insurance

When shopping around for car insurance it is important to be truthful, but how do you truthfully answer questions you don't know the answer to?

For instance, my current insurer doesn't list claims more than 3 years old, and it doesn't list who the insured driver was at all. But some insurers want to know all claims for the past 5 years for each person being quoted.

Is is preferable to just omit information and rely on them pulling the official report before quoting?  (Why do *I* have to answer all these questions anyway when this info is already in a big database somewhere?)  Should I just guess at the date?  What if I don't know how many claims there might have been?

I'm assuming that if I talked to an agent they could straighten all this out - but I'm also assuming that I would be paying a significant amount more for the same amount of coverage (at least this has always been the case when I asked my home owner's agent for a car insurance quote).

Comment: *I'm also assuming that I would be paying a significant amount more for the same amount of coverage* - probably not true, but it'll depend on what brands your agent or broker has access to. They get paid off commission from the insurer, you don't pay them. An indie broker who has access to a good portfolio of insurers is actually probably the best way to get the cheapest rate for a given set of terms. And they will be able to suggest discounts you may not be aware of, i.e. some brands offer multi-policy discounts if you do homeowners and auto together.

Comment: @dwizum Gotcha... in my case they were unable to get a better rate even from the same insurer I was using, even with a home + auto discount.   I don't know if it had anything to do with the fact that I had been with the company for a long time and had their next to highest level of perks (their highest being lifetime renewals)